# Above me sits a Seeing Hill, that rises to the sky, try to guess my longish name, what city am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is a rhyming riddle I came up with only a little while ago.

---

> My first four letters love to talk,
>
> the next three like some sun,
>
> the next pair are quite interested,
>
> the last, a State, we’re done.
>
> I am a city in a state,
>
> above the one before,
>
> our football team is really strong,
>
> Blue fire from the core.
>
> Above me is a town of stone,
>
> where crimson waters fall,
>
> My residents they often hear,
>
> A locomotive's call.

What city am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> **Chattanooga**

> My first four letters love to talk,

> Most people like to **Chat**

> the next three like some sun,

> If you go out in the sun, you might get a **tan**

> the next pair are quite interested,

> Someone interested, might say "**Oo**!"

> the last, a State, we’re done.

> State could mean country, or US state. In either case, **Ga** is Georgia

> I am a city in a state,
> above the one before,

> Tennessee is north of Georgia

> our football team is really strong,
> Blue fire from the core.

Thanks to @Rumpelstiltskin

> This is the state football team - the Tennessee Titans, who have a logo with blue flames

> Above me is a town of stone,
> where crimson waters fall,

Thanks to @ChrisCudmore

> This is Rock City and Ruby Falls.
>  Which are both at Lookout Mountain, which is the "Seeing Hill" referenced in the title.

> My residents they often hear,
> A locomotive's call.

> This is the famous Chattanooga Choo-choo immortalised by Glenn Miller

Comment: A bit of searching turned up rot13(Ebpx Pvgl naq Ehol Snyyf), tourist attractions in the area.  Still can't figure out Blue fire...

Comment: @ChrisCudmore the rot13(Graarffrr Gvgnaf flzoby) has blue flames.

Comment: Also, "Seeing Hill" refers to to a landform where those two tourist attractions are.

Comment: And "really strong" refers to the rot13(grnz anzr, gur Gvgbaf)